# Mechanize parsing error

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize

I started to use mechanize in ruby recently and it was working perfectly.
Today I tried to get a page but for some reason the input fields are not taken, please refer to the code below:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.add_auth(url, user, pass1, realm = nil, domain = nil)
agent.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
#agent.log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
page = agent.get(url)

page.forms.first.field_with(:name => 'Login[username]').value=user
page.forms.first.field_with(:name => 'Login[password]').value=pass2
page = agent.submit(page.forms.first)
page = page.link_with(:text => "Search").click
page = page.link_with(:text => "Spiral").click
pp page
```

The html page that Im trying to parse contains this line:

```
<input name="SpiralMatch_string" type="text" maxlength="128">
```

But for some reason there is nothing related to that when I dump the contents of the current "page"

There is one more thing that may be related, there is a java running below this field, every time I type something in it, the main contents of the page is dynamicaly changing. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: It looks like you've got three separate questions here; perhaps it'd be easier if you could construct an HTML file that demonstrates the first problem (_input fields are not taken_), another HTML file that demonstrates the second problem (_nothing related to that when I dump the contents_), and _definitely_ move the JavaScript-suggestions to a different question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the page may be getting populated through javascript or ajax calls.
Just because the browser shows you some html in 'view source' doesn't mean it actually in the response.
You should use a debugging proxy like charles or fiddler to see what the response(s) really looked like.

Comment: THanks for your answer I saw that mechanize is not the best tool for those javaScripts. I went with Watir it worked like a charm :)